# Convert Text link to Multiple HTML Format in Javascript with XSS Filter

Tags: javascript

I want to parse "string" and search "url" of various types like 
"**href**",  "**image**",  "**youtube**",  "**vimeo**", "**hashtag**",  "**mention**" with `@`

and convert them into "**HREF**" as well as other formats like **iframe**, "**img**" when available.

Following is my code, which is not working as it is supposed to be:

```
function convertLink(article) {

    var cArticle = "";
    cArticle = article.replace(/(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\ \r\n]+)/g, '<div id="$2" class="anotherClass" onclick="someFunction(\'$2\', \'$2\');"><img class="some-class" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$2/0.jpg"></div>')
                      .replace(/(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/([^\ \r\n]+)/g, '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$2" width="100%" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>')
                      .replace(/([\s+])@([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/$2'>@$2</a>").replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>")
                      .replace(/([\s+])#([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/#2'>#$2</a>").replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>")
                      .replace(/(\<br\>\<br\>)/, "<br>");

    return cArticle;
}
```

It only converts youtube link and ignores other following links.

Example of String:-

```
In this article, we will be talking about Some of the interesting facts like:
Youtube Flutter https://youtube.com/watch?v=someVideoID as well as https://example.com/images.jpg, https://vimeo.com/someVideoID and #rain @stackoverflow more coming soon at https://example.com/link/me Let's talk.
```

To get Converted to semi-html as below:-

```
In this article, we will be talking about some of the interesting facts like: <span class="someClass" onclick="someFunction(videoID)"><img src="https://.ytimg.com/vi/{vidoeID}/0.jpg"></span> as well as <img class="imgClass" src="https://example.com/images.jpg" /> , <div class="video-container"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/"></iframe></div> and <a href="https://example.com/#rain">#rain</a> <a href="https://example.com/@stackoverflow">@stackoverflow</a> and more coming soon at <a href="https://example.com/link/me">https://example.com/link/me</a>
```

So, if you see -

- https://example.com/images.jpg => becomes => `<img class="imgClass" src="https://example.com/images.jpg" />`
- https://youtube.com/watch?v=someVideoID => becomes => `<span class="someClass" onclick="someFunction(videoID)"><img src="https://.ytimg.com/vi/{vidoeID}/0.jpg"></span>`
- #rain => becomes => `<a href="https://example.com/#rain">#rain</a>`
- @stackoverflow => becomes => `<a href="https://example.com/@stackoverflow">@stackoverflow</a>`
- https://example.com/link/me => becomes => `<a href="https://example.com/link/me">https://example.com/link/me</a>`

image text link, youtube, Vimeo, and text link is converted to img, iframe and HTML link

**JsFiddle link here for Live Testing** - https://jsfiddle.net/thadg3uf/

```js
 function convertLink(article) {

    var cArticle = "";
    cArticle = article.replace(/(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\ \r\n]+)/g, '<div id="$2" class="anotherClass" onclick="someFunction(\'$2\', \'$2\');"><img class="some-class" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$2/0.jpg"></div>').replace(/(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/([^\ \r\n]+)/g, '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$2" width="100%" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>').replace(/([\s+])@([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/$2'>@$2</a>").replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>").replace(/([\s+])#([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/#2'>#$2</a>").replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>").replace(/(\<br\>\<br\>)/, "<br>");

    return cArticle;

    }  
    
    var stringIs = "In this article, we will be talking about Some of the interesting facts like: Youtube Flutterhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-Qy1VQUMuI as well as https://example.com/images.jpg, https://vimeo.com/259411563 and #rain @stackoverflow more coming soon at https://example.com/link/me Let's talk.";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = convertLink(stringIs);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Convert Link</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="demo"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Strictly No jQuery with XSS filter to avoid any XSS attack**

Comment: Hi, your code working fine just as you described, and I just need some clarification, 1) is it not working? if not which browser you are using for development? since I tested it on Chrome and FireFox and its working 2) is your question about how to make more secure and avoid XSS?

Comment: it is not working fine - it has some error, like "image link" is not getting converted to image URL and "simple link" is not getting converted to "html link", only "hashtag, mention, and video URL" is getting changed, others are getting error.

Comment: Ok, got your point here, can you add some sample that is not working inside the test article? that would help more understand and give some failing test cases.

Comment: Already added, if you see "https://example.com/images.jpg" below youtube video and this "https://example.com/link/me" at the end of the example is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the change you are looking for, What I did here (the snippet below) over what is your code doing. I add two replace statements,

- searched for all URLs and replaced them with links, this is to make sure that I don't override the other patterns we are replacing.
- searched for all href links with images extensions (I didn't add all image ext, you can add more as fits for your app) and replaced the whole  tag with  tag, I hope this help.

**Update**: Add XSS, in case your input is simple you can use a custom function to match patterns from XXS [OWASP XSS prevention sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) the only thing that didn't work for me is the '/' which I had to whitelist it, otherwise I really suggest to a library to [js-xss](https://github.com/leizongmin/js-xss) or [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to filter XSS potential text in your data input.

```js
function sanitizeString(str) {
  // "/": '&#x2F;',
  const patterns = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#x27;',
    "`": '&grave;'
  };
  const reg = /[&<>"']/ig;
  return str.replace(reg, (match)=>(patterns[match]));
}



function convertLink(article) {
  let cArticle = "";
  cArticle = article
    .replace(/(\bhttps?:\/\/\S+)/g, '<a href="$1">linked tag</a>')
    .replace(/<a href="((?:(https?):\/\/)([^\s]+)(\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))).">([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/g, '<img width="200" height="100" src="$1" />')
    .replace(/(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\ \r\n]+)/g, '<div id="$2" class="anotherClass" onclick="someFunction(\'$2\', \'$2\');"><img class="some-class" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$2/0.jpg"></div>')
    .replace(/<a href="(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/([^\ \r\n]+)">([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/g, '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$2" width="100%" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>')
    .replace(/([\s+])@([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/$2'>@$2</a>")
    .replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>")
    .replace(/([\s+])#([^\s]+)/g, " <a href='https:\/\/example.com/#2'>#$2</a>")
    .replace(/([\r\n])/ig, "<br>")
    .replace(/(\<br\>\<br\>)/, "<br>");
  return cArticle;
}
    
let stringIs = "In this article, we will be talking about Some of the interesting facts like: Youtube Flutterhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-Qy1VQUMuI as well as https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg, https://vimeo.com/259411563 and #rain @stackoverflow more coming soon at https://example.com/link/me Let's talk. here is XSS sample <div>Testing xss</div>";

stringIs = sanitizeString(stringIs);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = convertLink(stringIs);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Convert Link</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="demo"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not XSS safe

Comment: @JohnCargo I added some changes

Comment: thanks for the dompurify library, that will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You already have most of the things working for you, except "link", "hashtag" and "mention", for that I will recommend using - linkify ( https://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/docs/2.1.html )

It will solve your remaining part excluding the "image" tag.

For Image tag, you can use something like this, when the link is already converted to a tag:

```
jQuery('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif]"').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html('<img src="' + jQuery(this).attr('href') + '" />');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the linkifyjs, it was helpful, but no jquery. Need in pure JS